# window.renderCustomMView is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
class Pop extends Component{
     constructor(props){
         super(props);
         window.renderCustomMView = this.renderCustomMView.bind(this);

         }

     renderCustomMView(){
      ....some code
     }
}

const Popup = ()=>{
window.renderCustomMView();
}

export {Popup};
```

```
import {Popup} from 'path/to/parent';

class Video extends Component{
     constructor(props){
         super(props)
         }

     callingFunction(){
      Popup();
     }
}
```

When I import Popup it's imported. Then I call this function, it says window.renderCustomMView is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to instantiate `Pop` somewhere  so that `window.renderCustomMView = this.renderCustomMView.bind(this);` is run.

Of course, there's not an obvious way to do that here, because you typically organize differently in React. You should make `Popup` a child component of `Video` and then use standard React techniques to update the `Popup` state when `Video` wants to trigger it.